# Null values added in top when i apply order by Asc Cakephp 2.0

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2 . I have one column in my database i.e.  position. The position contains null values as well as numeric like i.e. 1,2,3

I have query like this

```
    $records= array('contain'=>array('ListingImage'),
    'conditions'=>$conditions,
    'fields'=>array('id','title','description','position','street','zipcode','keywords','latitude','longitude'),
    'order'=>'Listing.position ASC',
    'limit'=>10,
    'recursive'=>-1
 );
```

The following code gives me output like this:-

NULL,NULL, NULL, 1,2,3, etc

I want output something Like this:-

1,2,3,Null,Null,null

I want all null values at end

Can anyone help me . Thanks in advnace :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create **[virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)** and use mysql [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) like:

**EDIT:** add "END"

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'position_type' => 'CASE WHEN Listing.position IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
);
```

Then sort your data, first by virtual position_type (0,1), then by position(1,2,3..):

**EDIT:** order

```
'fields' => array('id', 'title', description', 'position', 'street', 'zipcode', 'keywords', 'latitude', 'longitude'),
'order'=> 'Listing.position_type ASC, Listing.position ASC',
'limit'=>10,
```

Or whitout creating virtual field:

```
'order'=> 'CASE WHEN Listing.position IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, Listing.position ASC',
```

Comment: not working it gives me output like : 3,2,1, null,null :(

Comment: Thank you so much salines :)